# in vtk, how to fuse the contour which get from vtkcutter into a mesh get from vtkimagereslice

Tags: libvtk9.1-qt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1f0j.png)

I slice the dicom object and get 3 reslice image show follow sub window,
and I cut the teeth stl model by a plane, and get the contour of the cut result,
now, how can I show the contour at the right position of the slice image at the sub window?
now, it is show as such:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XydW.png)
the red line is the contour of teeth cut, it is not on a same plane with the reslice image

I try to set the position of the contour , but it seems not work